# Can't load 2 different modal forms with JQuery Trigger

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I have some modal forms to complete some fields, in this case I have 2 modal forms, 1 for Jury and 1 for Contact, when I press 'Add' link, in both cases works fine, but the problem is when I want to edit contact.

When I press Edit in both cases I call controller to complete the Java form and then, return to view and simulate a click in "Add" button with JQuery. In jury case works fine, but in Contact I only get a dark screen (like if modal works), but modal window never appear. Other problem is, when I press Edit button in Jury and then close the jury modal form, when I press Edit in Contact it launch the jury modal form...

*Contact Modal and Add link* (**Edit link doesn't works**)

```
<div class="row margin-top-10">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-md-push-10">              
        <a id="btnAddCForm" href="#modal-cForm-form" data-toggle="modal" class="btn fpa btn-block pull-right">A&Ntilde;ADIR NUEVO</a>                   
    </div> 
</div>

<div id="modal-cForm-form" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo/Editar Forma de contacto</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="scroller" style="height:390px" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="1">
                      Some fields
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">CANCELAR</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="addContactForm();" class="btn fpa">ACEPTAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Jury Modal and Add link* (**Works fine**)

```
<div class="row margin-top-10">
    <div class="col-xs-2 col-md-2 col-md-push-10">              
        <a id="btnAddJurado" href="#modal-jury-form" data-toggle="modal" class="btn fpa btn-block pull-right">A&Ntilde;ADIR NUEVO</a>                   
    </div> 
</div>

<div id="modal-jury-form" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" onclick="resetValues();"></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Nuevo/Editar Jurado</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="scroller" style="height:300px" data-always-visible="1" data-rail-visible1="1">
                    Some Fields
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" onclick="resetValues();" class="btn default">CANCELAR</button>
                <button type="button" onclick="addJury();" class="btn fpa">ACEPTAR</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Onload* (In main html document)

```
window.onload = function () {

    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var idJuryAux = /*[[${person.juryAux.id}]]*/
    null;
    var idContactFormAux = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.id}]]*/
    null;
    /*]]>*/

    var idProvincia = $('#provinceField').val();
    var idPais = $('#countryField').val();
    if (idPais == '-1') {
        $('#provinceField').attr("readonly", true);
    } else {
        $('#provinceField').attr("readonly", false);
    }
    if (idProvincia == '-1') {
        $('#cityField').attr("readonly", true);
    } else {
        $('#cityField').attr("readonly", false);
    }
    if (idJuryAux != null) {
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var idCat = /*[[${person.juryAux.category}]]*/
        null;
        var idCargo = /*[[${person.juryAux.juryType}]]*/
        null;
        var catName = /*[[${person.juryAux.categoryName}]]*/
        null;
        var cargoName = /*[[${person.juryAux.juryTypeName}]]*/
        null;
        /*]]>*/
        $('#btnAddJurado').trigger('click');
        $("#categoryField").select2('data', {
            id: idCat,
            text: catName
        });
        $("#juryTypeField").select2('data', {
            id: idCargo,
            text: cargoName
        });
    }
    if (idContactFormAux != null) {
        /*<![CDATA[*/
        var idType = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.type}]]*/
        null;
        var typeName = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.typeName}]]*/
        null;
        var idTag = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.tag}]]*/
        null;
        var tagName = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.tagName}]]*/
        null;
        var idPais = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.country}]]*/
        null;
        var paisName = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.countryName}]]*/
        null;
        var idProvincia = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.province}]]*/
        null;
        var provName = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.provinceName}]]*/
        null;
        var idCity = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.city}]]*/
        null;
        var cityName = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.cityName}]]*/
        null;
        var idInst = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.institution}]]*/
        null;
        var instName = /*[[${person.contactFormAux.institutionNme}]]*/
        null;
        /*]]>*/

        $('#btnAddCForm').trigger('click');
        $("#typeField").select2('data', {
            id: idType,
            text: typeName
        });
        $("#tagField").select2('data', {
            id: idTag,
            text: tagName
        });
        $("#countryField").select2('data', {
            id: idPais,
            text: paisName
        });
        $("#provinceField").select2('data', {
            id: idProvincia,
            text: provName
        });
        $("#cityField").select2('data', {
            id: idCity,
            text: cityName
        });
        $("#institutionField").select2('data', {
            id: idInst,
            text: instName
        });
    }
}
```

P.S. addJury(); and addContactForm(); only closes modal window, both works fine!

EDIT: I'm still waiting for a response...

Comment: Seems like your modal fade overlay didn't disappeared

Comment: And did you know why?, if I dont't load Jury modal, when I try to launch Contact Modal with Edit button only shows fade but is the 1st time I load a modal in page...